# Delete characters in string until /r/n

Tags: android, string

I have long string that at some part has

some text + "PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=JPEG:" + some characters that generate randomly + /r/n...

I am wondering how can I delete part from

"PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=JPEG:" untill /r/n

so I will be left only with

some text + /r/n ?

my code so far:

```
if (string.contains("PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=JPEG:") {
   string = string.replace("PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=JPEG:", "");
}
```

but this obviously would not replace my random generated chars, only "PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=JPEG:".

How do I "loop through" string from "PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=JPEG:" untill /r/n ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final String input = "some text + PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=JPEG: + some characters that generate randomly + /r/n"
final int index = input.indexOf("PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=JPEG:");
if (index != -1)
{ 
    final String result = input.subString(0, index) + System.getProperty("line.separator")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why dont you try following

```
1) Get the index of "PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=JPEG:". and call it idx
2)If idx != -1 then take substring of original string using str.subString(0,idx) and call it newStr
3)return newStr+(str.endsWith("\r\n")?"\r\n":"")
```